# Single Elimination Tournament Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, tournament

I am new to this field, and i wanted to do a Java application implementing the technique of Single Elimination Tournament that will have me importing player names and their clubs and let the app ( through an algorithm ) create for me a single elimination tournament bracket with names of players based on a specific criteria , like : Two players from the same club CANNOT play against each other or Two players that have won previous championships CANNOT play against each other....etc

Anyway how can i start such an algorithm ?

Comment: How long must those criteria hold? If they only need to hold at the lowest level of the bracket, then you just have to arrange it so that no two players from the same club are next to each other. If you want your criteria to hold for at least two levels of the bracket, then players from the same club cannot be in the same set of four ({0,1,2,3} or {4,5,6,7} or ...). Also, what happens if your criteria are self-contradictory? As a simple example, if over half the players are from the same club, you cannot avoid two players from the same club playing against one another at the first level.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the issue about two players who have won previous championships, and just thinking about clubs, this is what I suggest. First, add another club called BYE with enough players {bye0, bye1, ...} so that the total number of players is 2^n for some n. (2 gives n=1, 4 gives n=2, 8 gives n=3, 16 gives n=4, ...).

We build the tournament bracket by working from the root of a tree, down n levels. At the root, we have all of our players. To move down a level, half the players have to go left, half have to go right. Try splitting each club in half at that stage, so that half of the players in club 0 go to the left, the other half of the players in club 0 go to the right. The only complication that you will have to deal with is odd numbers, but since there must be an even number of odd-sized clubs, the odd man out can go alternately to the left and to the right.

Continue recursively down the tree in that manner. In the end you should have a distribution of players and byes in the lowest level of the bracket which is as uniform as possible.